# Zero-free regions for the Dedekind zeta-function

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hello,

What is the standard reference (including proofs) for a $\sigma>1-\frac{A}{\log t}$ type zero-free region for the Dedekind zeta-function and also, order estimates for $\zeta_K(s)$ and $\frac{1}{\zeta_K(s)}$  as $t\to\infty$ in such regions?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Iwaniec-Kowalski? Chapter 5, if I'm not mistaken. I'm not sure if the proofs are included, but it most certainly is a standard reference.

Comment: Of course there is no such zero-free region in general, and you'll have to deal with possible Landau-Siegel zeros in general (e.g., for quadratic fields).


Comment: (Though I am thinking here of the dependency with respect to the field; there's no problem if it's really the t-aspect, and nothing else, which matters.)

Comment: Yes, I just need a region for a fixed field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a proof in the paper of Lagarias and Odlyzko on the effective Chebotarev density theorem.